# How to get principal from Amazon Cognito code/token

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, saml, amazon-cognito

I'm going to use Amazon Cognito to provide user authentication for my app.

For now, I set up integration so I have auth code/token after the user logged in the Cognito. But what the next? How can I get any useful info (fx. email) using the token?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html

Answer (score 0):

How u added ur user in aws cognito while sign in facebook app via authentication